# Outputting data to a file on android, not sure where it's going or if it's going anywhere

Tags: java, android, file-io, stream, storage

I am trying to output numeric values one at a time from an Android application I'm writing, but I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out what's going on. Tried looking for answers, but only confused further. This strikes me as something that should be relatively straightforward, so I feel pretty dumb for being so confused by it.

```
String directory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
```

When I log the directory I get a path "/storage/emulated/0" Where is that? Is that different from what I would get if I wasn't debugging?

Then I have:

```
String fileName = directory + "/Android/data/com.sample.app/files/test.txt"
File myFile = new File(fileName);
FileOutputStream fos;
try { 
    fos = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
    String text = "Test text\n";
    fos.write(text.getBytes());
fos.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I tried using the Windows Explorer to figure out where stuff is saving and/or is supposed to be saved but I don't see it. This is code based on the information in this link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html, but I really don't understand where the "/storage/emulated/0" comes from and how I either access that location or get rid of it.

EDIT: Right now I just want to save all the numbers so I can check what is coming out. The numbers are recorded from the audio input.

EDIT: Using the ASTRO File app on my phone revealed the files
Didn't need the "/Android/data/com.sample.app/files/" part, don't know how to use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Path wrong?**

`/storage/emulated/0` is a path at your filesystem which represents the external storage. At earlier versions of Android we often had `/mnt/sdcard/` or something similiar, but many devices today don't have a sdcard but emulate an external storage anyway.

To view the files at your Android filesystem I'd recommend to use an App like [Astro File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.metago.astro). Just take a look if your file has been written.

One possible mistake could be, that you you are missing a `File.separator` between your `directory` and the local path.

```
String fileName = directory + File.seperator + "Android/data/com.sample.app/file/test.txt"
```

**Directory created?**

You should also make sure, that the directory exists by calling `myDir.mkDirs();`, where `myDir` is the complete path without the filename.

To create the directory you can use the following code

```
directory = directory + "/Android/data/com.sample.app/file/test.txt" 
new File(directory).mkDirs();
```

**Uses-Permission in Manifest?**

Last error source could be, that you might miss the external storage permission, you need a

You also need to make sure, that you require the permission for writing to the external storage. Take a look for `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` in your Android Manifest file.

Comment: Thanks. I just downloaded that app, so I'm looking at it. I do have the permission set, the separate was there just a typo (now fixed) in the question text. I'm not sure what "mkDirs()" is. Doesn't seem to be a function that you can call on a string.
EDIT: So using that app I was able to find the things I had saved. How do I see them on my computer though?

Comment: `mkDirs()` can only be called at `File`, but if you could find the file you don't seem to have problems with non-created directories.

If your test-file has been stored to `/storage/emulated/0` you should be able to see it when you connect your phone as a masstorage device via USB.

Comment: The file I'm seeing is one that was made without the "Android/data/com.sample.app/file part" I just wrote it at the external storage directory.

Comment: But the files don't appear in the Windows Explorer view of my devices internal storage. Guess I can just send them from the phone though, should be good enough.

Comment: Strange that you can't see it at the **external** storage of your device when it's mounted to your PC.

Regard the directory issue you should do something like this:

    `directory = directory + "/Android/data/com.sample.app/file/test.txt"
    new File(directory).mkDirs();`

and then execute the file writting code you already have.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problems. The files exist when viewed from an internal app on the device, but when mounted on an MTP connection to Windows, it won't show. I suspect it has to do with the MTP protocol.